# Resize and Center Google Map on Window Resize

Tags: google-maps

How can I make this Google Map resize and center on phone devices?

I'm using WordPress and http://gmap3.net/ .

I've already tried a number of solutions found on WordPress.org

Can anybody help with this?

```
$(".gmap").gMap({
    controls: {
        panControl: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        draggable: true,
        overviewMapControl: false
    },
    scrollwheel: false,
    draggable: false,
    markers: [{
        latitude: 41.62552,
        longitude: -81.44203
    }],
    icon: {
        image: 'img/pin',
        iconsize: [32, 48],
        iconanchor: [16, 24],
        infowindowanchor: [0, 0]
    },
    latitude: 41.62552,
    longitude: -81.44203,
    zoom: 12
})
var myGmap = $('.gmap').data('gMap.reference');

var styles = [{
    "featureType": "all",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [{
        "invert_lightness": true
    }, {
        "saturation": 10
    }, {
        "lightness": 40
    }, {
        "gamma": 0.6
    }, {
        "hue": "#1079bf"
    }]
}, {


    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [{
        "color": "#99CC66"
    }]
}, {
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [{
        "color": "#ffffff"
    }, {
        "visibility": "simplified"
    }]

}]
var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(
    styles, {
        name: "Styled Map"
    }
);
myGmap.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
myGmap.setMapTypeId('map_style');
});
```

Comment: Are you talking about css media queries for narrow views of the map? Can you please explain your goal in more detail?

Comment: When I resize the window or view on mobile device the map is not centered on the map pin located at latitude: 41.62552, longitude: -81.44203,

Answer (score 0):

It might be different for the plugin, but for google maps if you put something like this in the initialize function it will center as the browser resizes.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function () {
    map.setCenter({ lat: 41.62552, lng: -81.44203 });
});
```